# migrating carriage returns from oracle to sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008

I've been trying to migrate some carriage returns from an oracle varchar2 field to a sql server varchar field and it's not working at all.

I had working code in Oracle of the form:

'**_*Person making Contact*__**' ||chr(13) ||

which works perfectly fine in Oracle, but seems to get lost by the time SSIS has extracted the data to sql server.

I tried to pass the below:

```
  'Name: ' || nvl2(p.surname || p.forename ,p.surname || ', ' || p.forename,'None Recorded') || 'char(13)' ||
  'Organisation: ' || nvl(a.agency_name, 'None Recorded') 
  as ContactDetails
```

but the carriage returns end up embedded as text.  e.g "Person making Contact_*_*_char(13)Name: None"

I've tried replacing the char (13) in various ways at the sqlserver end but cannot get the results to be anything other than char(13)s embedded in the text.

e.g

`update mytable set [ContactDetails] = REPLACE(contactdetails,'char(13)',CHAR(13))
update mytable set [ContactDetails] = REPLACE(contactdetails,'char(13)',''' + CHAR(13) + ''' )`

Things like `"select myfield + char(13) + 'test text'` give me the results I'm after so I can rule out really daft mistakes.

Can anyone offer any suggestions? At Oracle or sqlserver end is fine by me :)

Comment: In your concatenation you have char(13) inside quotes that's why it's embedded as text; try removing the quotes and it should be fine.

Comment: The quotes are there because that is pl/sql, which does not recognise char(13), only the pl/sql equivalent chr(13). Apologies if that wasnt clear. Your comment has however prompted me to find the actual answer, so thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't know how this didn't work before but Jayvee has pointed me in the right direction. Re-tested this and it works now...

update mytable
set [ContactDetails] = REPLACE(contactdetails,'char(13)',CHAR(13))

Thanks all

Comment: Did you simplify the code or is it really just chr(13)?  It is unusual to have chr(13) without chr(10) - see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/01/the-great-newline-schism.html

Comment: yep - chr(13) seemed to do the job fine. I only ever viewed this code through pl/sql developer though. A different viewer may have given different results.